# How to parametrize string.format() format specification?

Tags: python, string, parameter-passing, string-formatting

I have a variable `line_number_max_digits` and I want to use it in string format specification as [`width`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#grammar-token-width) token. I have come up with the following code:

```
print ('{0:>%d}: {1}' % line_number_max_digits).format(lineno + i, chunk)
```

But I understand that percent formatting will eventually go away from Python. I could use [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) or use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) two times but it would make my code less clear:

```
print ('{{0:>{0}}}: {{1}}').format(line_number_max_digits).format(lineno + i, chunk)
```

Which way is considered a good practice in such situations?

Comment: I'd put them in separate lines generating the format string first, then the formatted result.  Inlining it like that makes it less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limited nesting support.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/KnogR)

```
print('{1:>{0}}: {2}'.format(line_number_max_digits, lineno + i, chunk))
```